# Array that doesn't return the correct value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview, backendless

I am trying to set up a following/ follower system for my app. I have set up the decoration and it displays. My problem is that it displays as always true even when I know it should be false. I have tried various if statements and I can't seem to use the correct variable or constant to run a check so that the array will return true or false. The array is isFollowing[false] initialized in that way.

## Relevant Code

```
self.backendless.persistenceService.of(BackendlessUser.ofClass()).find( query, response: { ( objectId : BackendlessCollection!) -> () in
    let currentPage = objectId.getCurrentPage()

    for objects in currentPage as! [BackendlessUser] {

        if (objects.objectId != self.backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId) {

            self.userids.append(objects.objectId)
            self.backendless.persistenceService.of(objects.ofClass()).find( query, response: { objects -> () in

                    if let objects = objects {
                        self.isFollowing.append(true)
                    } else {
                        self.isFollowing.append(false)
                    }

                    if self.isFollowing.count == self.usernames.count{
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })
                    }
                }, error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in
                    print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
                }
            )
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Perhaps if let _objects = objects where objects.count > 0 {   or some additional checks. All you are checking for is if the array is nil or not. Just because its not nil doesn't mean it has objects in it.

Comment: I actually tried that and it didn't work. It says that.count is not part of BacendlessCollection

Comment: I assumed objects is an array. BackendlessCollection is a specific object that you need to check for data. https://github.com/Backendless/iOS-Samples/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=BackendlessCollection says it has a property called data that is an array that may or may not contain the data you should check for. The bottom line is you need to check for more than just nil on that object.

Comment: I can't seem to find where I need to pull the data from. The idea is that I need to check if the current user is following certain userId's if the user is there should be a check mark if not then there shouldn't be one. The check I would need to do is find which userID's the user if following, but I am not sure how to check that.

Comment: Examine the "objects" returned carefully. Since that is what resulted from the method, what you are looking for is in there somewhere.

Comment: what is `query` and why are you running it multiple times ?